# mpdf download not working on server using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mpdf

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pages.qrdownload', compact('qr_code'));
return $pdf->download('event_qrcode.pdf');
```

When I try to download the pdf file using m pdf package, in rare case pdf was download otherwise pdf download was cancelled.

[image: this pic shows the error of cancelled pdf.]

[image]

Above pic shows the error of cancelled pdf.

Comment: it's seems like the server errors. does it give same error in your local ?

Comment: Which package do you use?

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi he has already writen the package name "mPDF"

Comment: this package ? https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Comment: plese give me url

Comment: @DivyeshPatel On local it works perfectly. Yes, you are right It is not working on server.

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi I used this package : https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf

Comment: i think there is an error with your view file please debug your view

Comment: do you use any `AdBlock` extension?

Comment: No I don't use any AdBlock extension

Comment: It may be due to one of the browser extensions. Please disable all and then test it. Or use another browser.

Comment: Hmm. The fact that it cancels after exactly 2.00 seconds might indicate that your server has a very low time out and just can't generate the pdf in time. Could you check the server and/or php timeout?

Comment: @Loek Thanks Bro! It works after increase timeout of server. :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help :) Added as an answer for reference :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference (original answer in the comments):

The fact that it cancels after exactly 2.00 seconds might indicate that your server has a very low time out and just can't generate the pdf in time. Check the server and/or php timeouts and increase them if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

For increase the http and ftp timeout in ubuntu server this are the steps,
 1. Navigate to Directory /etc/apt/apt.conf.d(cd /etc/apt/apt.conf.d)
 2. Create a new file eg. 99timeout(touch 99timeout)
 3. Open that file (vi 99timeout).
 4. Paste below lines for make it for 10 sec.

```
  Acquire::http::Timeout "10";
  Acquire::ftp::Timeout "10";
```

5. Save the file (esc :wq)
6. Restart the server.

Comment: Although this can be useful, what does a config file for apt have to do with an apache web server? Apache timeout is configured in `httpd.conf` and php timeout is configured in `php.ini` or in the php-fpm config. This doesn't answer the question and the steps provided don't solve the problem.